# Unable to update the Maven Configuration

Tags: java, maven, m2eclipse

I tried almost all the question related to Maven update project error but nothing workout.

I have maven project which I am unable to update via right click on the project => Maven => Update Project option.

snapshot for the same:
[image]

Whtat it says that your are using the App Engine libs and it uses JRE8 for Dynamic Web project and version matching is blocking the maven update.

Let me show you the JRE and Dynamic Web Module version as well.
[image]

Now I am totally blind that is the problem which is causing this issue. please help any suggestions and answer is welcome.

Comment: Check you'r META-INF/web.xml it must be in 3.1 format. Otherwise, Eclipse will failing to update project facets. It seems like you have it in 4.0 format.

Comment: `mvn -U clean install` try this

Comment: I just have WEB-INF folder where i have web.xml which is having web-app tags only nothing much, are you saying that from Project facets this Dynamic Web Module has to be 3.1 instead of 4?

Comment: @VishwaRatna I tried with "mvn -U clean install" but when i do the m2e maven project as mentioned throw the same error.